# Unable to print query using Miniprofiler

Tags: c#, .net, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I have integrated Entity Framework and CodeFirstStoredProc library in my project. I want to log the queries executed by both the libraries. Previously I was using Database.Log delegate provided by EF but as I want to log query from other libraries also, I decided to integrated Miniprofiler for the same.

I used below code to get the query log in `result` variable:

```
MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
        MiniProfiler.StartNew("Test");
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Level 1"))
        {
            DbConnection spConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            ProfiledDbConnection profileSpConnection = new ProfiledDbConnection(spConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);
            using (EfDataContext db = new EfDataContext(profileSpConnection))
            {
                List<Domain.PersonEntity> data = db.Persons.ToList();
            }
            using (StoredProcedureContext db = new StoredProcedureContext(profileSpConnection))
            {
                List<GetPersonResult> data = db.GetPerson.CallStoredProc(new Domain.GetPersonParameter { IsActive = true }).ToList<GetPersonResult>();
            }
            string result = MiniProfiler.Current.RenderPlainText();
        }
        MiniProfiler.Current.Stop();
```

I expected the output query with all the details but unfortunately I am getting below result:

```
Manprit-PC at 11/15/2018 2:24:27 PM
 Test = ms
> Level 1 = ms (sql = 45ms in 12 cmds)
```

Am I missing something for the implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just how current version of [`MiniProfilerExtensions.RenderPlainText()`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/src/MiniProfiler.Shared/MiniProfilerExtensions.cs) renders custom timing information. Custom timings are created using `CustomTiming()` rather then `Step()`, they typically are sort of leaf measurements in a MiniProfiler hierarchy such as database interaction or HTTP requests.

You can easily customize rendering process and render verbose information about custom timings:

```
SERVER at 23.11.2018 09:00:00
 MiniProfiler = 48,3[ms]
> Foo = 35,6ms (sql = 24,8[ms] in 1 cmd) (http = 4,7[ms] in 1 cmd)
   sql 24,8[ms] +16,9[ms] SELECT * FROM Foo
   http 4,7[ms] +41,8[ms] GET http://foo.bar
```

Example implementation:

```
using StackExchange.Profiling;
using StackExchange.Profiling.Internal;
...
public static string CustomRenderPlainText(this MiniProfiler profiler, bool htmlEncode = false)
{
    if (profiler == null) return string.Empty;

    var text = StringBuilderCache.Get()
        .Append(htmlEncode ? WebUtility.HtmlEncode(Environment.MachineName) : Environment.MachineName)
        .Append(" at ")
        .Append(DateTime.UtcNow)
        .AppendLine();

    var timings = new Stack<Timing>();
    timings.Push(profiler.Root);

    while (timings.Count > 0)
    {
        var timing = timings.Pop();

        text.AppendFormat("{0} {1} = {2:###,##0.##}[ms]",
            new string('>', timing.Depth),
            htmlEncode ? WebUtility.HtmlEncode(timing.Name) : timing.Name,
            timing.DurationMilliseconds);

        if (timing.HasCustomTimings)
        {
            // TODO: Customize this code block.

            // Custom timings grouped by category. Collect all custom timings in a list.
            var customTimingsFlat = new List<KeyValuePair<string, CustomTiming>>(capacity: timing.CustomTimings.Sum(ct => ct.Value.Count));
            foreach (var pair in timing.CustomTimings)
            {
                var type = pair.Key;
                var customTimings = pair.Value;

                customTimingsFlat.AddRange(pair.Value.Select(ct => KeyValuePair.Create(type, ct)));
                text.AppendFormat(" ({0} = {1:###,##0.##}[ms] in {2} cmd{3})",
                    type,
                    customTimings.Sum(ct => ct.DurationMilliseconds),
                    customTimings.Count,
                    customTimings.Count == 1 ? string.Empty : "s");
            }

            foreach (var pair in customTimingsFlat.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.StartMilliseconds))
            {
                var type = pair.Key;
                var ct = pair.Value;

                text.AppendLine();
                var mainPart = string.Format("{0}{1} {2:###,##0.##}[ms] +{3:###,##0.##}[ms] ",
                                    new string(' ', timing.Depth + 2),
                                    type,
                                    ct.DurationMilliseconds,
                                    ct.StartMilliseconds);
                text.Append(mainPart);
                // Shift command text to closer to the command for better readability.
                var prefix = new string(' ', mainPart.Length);
                string cmdLine = null;
                using (var reader = new StringReader(ct.CommandString))
                {
                    while ((cmdLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        text.Append(cmdLine);
                        if (reader.Peek() == -1 && profiler.Options.ExcludeStackTraceSnippetFromCustomTimings)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        text.AppendLine();
                        text.Append(prefix);
                    }
                }

                if (profiler.Options.ExcludeStackTraceSnippetFromCustomTimings)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                text.Append(ct.StackTraceSnippet);
            }
        }

        text.AppendLine();

        if (timing.HasChildren)
        {
            var children = timing.Children;
            for (var i = children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) timings.Push(children[i]);
        }
    }

    return text.ToStringRecycle();
}
```

Also note that by default in order to render MiniProfiler report with all timings you need to call `Stop()` first. You can customize this too by calculating timings so far in a report.

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems that the current implementation of MiniProfiler is not creating custom timings with the actual SQL command text. I'm using Dapper.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT it certainly should. But you need to utilize `ProfiledDbConnection` decorator. See [How-To Profile SQL Server (…or anything else using ADO.NET)](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/HowTo/ProfileSql) page on MiniProfiler documentation.

Comment: I am, but I must be missing something because with the IDbProfiler set to MiniProfiler.Current I have the basic result when calling your extension method. HasCustomTimings is false

Comment: @OlivierMATROT without additional info it is impossible to say what the issue is. Please ask a separate question with all details and I will look at it.

Answer (score 1):

When profiling EntityFramework 6, you need to hook things up *before the first query*. So that `.Initialize()` call needs to happen much earlier, when your application starts up. You can find [the MiniProfiler EF6 docs here](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/HowTo/ProfileEF6)

Given the tags, it looks like you're in a web application, so it should happen early like this:

```
using StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework6;

protected void Application_Start()
{
    MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
}
```

Comment: ♦: I am using Console Application and I have already added `MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();` at first line.