# MiniProfiler and EF Core 3

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, miniprofiler

I cannot seem get it working. My situation:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.22 (cannot upgrade)
- MiniProfiler.EntityFrameworkCore 4.2.22
- No `IServiceProvider` (legacy code base, cannot upgrade)

So I'm trying to use it like [in a console app](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/ConsoleDotNetCore):

```
    MiniProfiler.Configure(MiniProfiler.DefaultOptions).AddEntityFramework();

    using SqlConnection sqlConnection = new(ConnectionString);

    DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext> optionsBuilder = new();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(sqlConnection);

    var profiler = MiniProfiler.StartNew("M");
    var ctx = new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

    using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Query"))
    {
        var actual = ctx.Set<PLine>().Take(1).ToArray();
    }

    string profilerText = profiler.RenderPlainText();
```

The context is OK and the query is working (I can see in in SQL Profiler). My expectation is  that `profilerText` would contain all sql text going to my SQL Server. Instead, all I see is something like this:

```
VM3 at 2022-03-16 4:40:27 PM
M 0ms
>> Query 3,599.9ms (sql = 456.8ms in 3 cmds)
```

I also tried to wrap the connection with `ProfiledDbConnection` with no result. What am I missing?

Comment: The code base targets .NET 4.8 and we're trying to upgrade EF6 to EF Core. Since we cannot upgrade directly to EF Core 5/6 we must use EF Core 3.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53321634/unable-to-print-query-using-miniprofiler  The default RenderPlainText() won't have details rendered from the Steps which is where the profiler would drill down to individual queries.