# Show all the timings with MiniProfiler

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core, .net-6.0, miniprofiler

I am using MiniProfiler to check the performance of my API.

I have instrumented my API code with the MiniProfiler statements, and at the end of the API method I call `MiniProfiler.RenderPlainText();` to print the performance log and save it on my DB.

Unfortunately, this printout seems "cut" in the middle and is not complete.

This is true for printouts of 24M characters, as well as of 350k characters, so it doesn't seem to be a problem of some kind of threshold.

Do you know how can I obtain the full log?

Another (sub-optimal) strategy could be to configure MiniProfiler to skip the trivial timing (e.g. < 0.2ms) and print only the relevant ones...

Let me know if there is a solution to this issue please.

Thank you!

cghersi

Comment: did you see this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53448770/9247039) by any chance ?

Comment: thanks @CodingMytra but I am perfectly fine with the default formatting, I just want the full resulting string!